# Why does Java pack does not size frame properly when textarea is used with other components?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a GUI using GridLayout to arrange multiple panels that are using FlowLayout.  I am using pack to determine the size of the frame.  If I have only a TextArea then it sizes correctly.  If I have only other components it sizes correctly.  But if I use both p1 and p2 in the code below the panel with the buttons does not size properly.  The test code I am using is below.  If I use only p1 or p2 it sizes properly, but not with both:  Here is the image I am getting.  I don't want all that extra space between the buttons and the textarea. 
 If I do textarea alone it sizes properly.:  [image]

```
public class GUIPractice extends JFrame
{
    //declare GUI objects
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel p1, p2;
    JButton btnAdd, btnShow;
    JScrollPane js;
    JTextArea taOutput; 

    //constructor
    public GUIPractice()
    {
        //give frame a title
        setTitle("GUI Practice");
        panel =new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnShow = new JButton("Show");
        taOutput = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        js = new JScrollPane(taOutput, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(btnAdd);
        p1.add(btnShow);

        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(js);

        panel.add(p1);
        panel.add(p2);

        //add the panel to the frame
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GUIPractice frame = new GUIPractice();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to post an image or a link to an image of what you're trying to achieve and what you are actually seeing

Comment: sure, what is the preferred way to post an image please?

Comment: Create your images, then edit the question and try to upload them. It will fail (your reputation is too low), but then comment back to us and we can finish the upload for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sizes correctly. The `GridLayout` means that all cells will be the same size. Since the text area is bigger than the buttons, you see extra space in the panel containing the buttons.

I would suggest you just use the default `BorderLayout` of the frame.

There is no need for your "panel" using the GridLayout.

You just use:

```
add(p1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now the p1 and p2 will be the proper height.

Also, there really is no need for "p2". You can just add the scroll pane directly to the frame.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now!  GridLayout is not a good choice with different sized components.  Thanks much!

Comment: I can continue to add more rows this way?  I will experiment.

Comment: No you can't add more rows, The BorderLayout has fixed constraints. If you want more vertical rows you need to use different layout managers and nested panels with appropriate layout managers depending on your exact requirement. Read the Swig tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on each of the layout mangers.